# How do I access a uint64 in a VARIANT structure?

Tags: visual-c++, wmi, variant, uint64

How do I access a `uint64` in a `VARIANT` structure?

Eg:

```
VARIANT vtProp{};
hres = pclsObj->Get(L"FreeSpaceInPagingFiles", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Free Space In Paging Files: %d\r\n", vtProp.iVal);
```

These are properties from the [`Win32_ComputerSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem) class.

---

I don't understand why I get:

```
Total Virtual Memory Size: 1860884006920
Total Visible Memory Size: 1860884006920
```

with this code:

```
hres = pclsObj->Get(L"TotalVirtualMemorySize", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Total Virtual Memory Size: %lld\r\n", vtProp.ullVal);
VariantClear(&vtProp);

hres = pclsObj->Get(L"TotalVisibleMemorySize", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
strSystemInfo.AppendFormat(L"  Total Visible Memory Size: %lld\r\n", vtProp.ullVal);
VariantClear(&vtProp);
```

But PowerShell:

> ```
> Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_operatingsystem" | Format-List *
> ```

Reports:

```
TotalVirtualMemorySize                    : 35567932
TotalVisibleMemorySize                    : 33470780
```

What am I doing wrong?

For example, for `Win32_ComputerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory` the docs say:

> `TotalPhysicalMemory`
>
> Data type: `uint64`
>
> Access type: Read-only
>
> Qualifiers: MappingStrings ("Win32API|Memory Management Structures|MEMORYSTATUS|dwTotalPhys"), Units ("bytes")
>
> Total size of physical memory. Be aware that, under some circumstances, this property may not return an accurate value for the physical memory. For example, it is not accurate if the BIOS is using some of the physical memory. For an accurate value, use the Capacity property in [`Win32_PhysicalMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemory) instead.
>
> Example: 67108864
>
> For more information about using `uint64` values in scripts, see [Scripting in WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/creating-a-wmi-script).

To be honest, it doesn't matter which memory value properties I use as I struggle to interpret the `VARIANT` object data correctly.

Comment: [`__VARIANT_NAME_1.__VARIANT_NAME_2.__VARIANT_NAME_3.ullVal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-variant)?

Comment: @phuclv But the docs say a ullVal is a ULONGLONG An unsigned 8-byte integer value. So is that uint64? I am confused.

Comment: @phuclv and I think I should be using %lld as the format specifier then.

Comment: no `%lld` is for `long long int`. For `unsigned long long` it must be `%llu`

Comment: @phuclv OK, but as per my answer, it seems we need to use `bstrVal`.

Comment: @phuclv See: https://imgur.com/aMnrhvj. This is why I have gone with `bstrVal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have part of the answer:

[image]

The value is correct in `bstrVal`.

So ,taking the `Capacity`, I get:

```
Total Physical Memory: 17179869184
Total Physical Memory: 17179869184
```

The values match PowerShell:

```
Capacity             : 17179869184
```

I have 2 banks, so the total is `34359738368`. And this is similar to `Win32_ComputerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory` -> `Installed RAM: 34274078720`.

The short answer is that I can use `bstrVal` to get the actual value that PowerShell displays. But how I turn that `bstrVal` into a suitable GB value is another story.

---

For the latter query:

```
const double totalMemoryBytes = _tstof(CString(vtProp.bstrVal));
const double totalMemoryKilobytes = totalMemoryBytes / 1024.0;
const double totalMemoryMegabytes = totalMemoryKilobytes / 1024.0;
const double totalMemoryGigabytes = totalMemoryMegabytes / 1024.0;
```